# An Hilbert subset closed and eventually compact

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $(u_n)_{n \in N}$ an orthonormal set and $(b_n)_{n \in N}$ a sequence of non-negative numbers, prove that

$M:= \{x | x= \sum_{n} c_nu_n  with |c_k| \leq b_k, \forall k \in N \}$

(i) is close
(ii) is compact if and only if $\sum_n b_n^2$ converges

For the first thing, i can see that
$M= \cap_{k \in N} \{x | x= \sum_{n} c_nu_n  with |c_k| \leq b_k\}$
Those might be close sets, but I dont know how to prove that.
And for the second point, I cant think anything useful for now.

Comment: (i) The coordinate projections $x \mapsto x_k$ are continuous. (ii) Compact sets are bounded, and a subset of $H$ is compact if and only if it is closed and totally bounded.

Comment: The first point is trivial then, but the second looks tricky. I'll try to find a way